# Removing Views dynamically

Tags: android, view, onclicklistener, layout-inflater

I search a lot for this, but I can't solve it. I have LinearLayout with two textviews and a button (to add others LinearLayout) like this:

```
         <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

             <EditText android:id="@+id/ingredientsField"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/boxes_margin"
                    android:hint="@string/ingredients"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />

             <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/quantityField"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/boxes_margin"
                    android:hint="@string/quantity"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    />

             <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/add_ingredient_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/add"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/boxes_margin"
                    app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_ingr_btn"
                    />

         </LinearLayout>
```

The layout added is like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/ingredientsField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/boxes_margin"
        android:hint="@string/ingredients"
        android:inputType="text"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/quantityField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/boxes_margin"
        android:hint="@string/quantity"
        android:inputType="number"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/remove_ingredient_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/boxes_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_remove_ing_qnt"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the Activity, I created a method to add new Layouts (and it works), and inside of it a method to delete the corresponding Layout with the **Delete Button**. Delete Button works only one time and only if it's in the first layout added. Here's the code:

```
    add_ingredient.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ingredient_quantity_layout, null);
            // Add the new row before the add field button.
            parentIngredientLayout.addView(rowView);

            ImageButton removeChildIngredient = findViewById(R.id.remove_ingredient_btn);

            removeChildIngredient.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   parentIngredientLayout.removeView((View) v.getParent());
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `OnClickListener`event on the `ImageButton` from the last inserted layout.
To do that, just change this line

`ImageButton removeChildIngredient = findViewById(R.id.remove_ingredient_btn);`

to

`ImageButton removeChildIngredient = rowView.findViewById(R.id.remove_ingredient_btn);`

`rowView.findViewById` search the ImageButton on the last inserted layout and not the whole layout which contains other layouts.

Answer (score 1):

In this line :

```
parentIngredientLayout.removeView((View) 
  v.getParent());
```

You are trying to remove the parent of the removeChildIngredient ImageButton, which is probably parentIngredientLayout, which i think is not what you want,

You could try this :

```
parentIngredientLayout.
removeView(rowView);
```

But in your implementation, you could encounter issues when you will add multiples ingredients, because you are setting a new onClickListener to each new ingredient, and The ImageButton will only delete the last one you have added(the last onClickListener set),

Instead, you could use a List/RecyclerView or search for another implementation, eg. put the ImageButton inside the Inflated Layout so you'll have one Remove Button in each Layout you add,

Then you should replace the findViewById of your ImageButton by rowView.findViewById

And this line should stay unchanged

```
parentIngredientLayout.removeView((View) v.getParent());
```